# Working with nested hashes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, nested

I'm working with the Koala gem and the Facebook Graph API, and I want to break down the results I get for a users feed into separate variables for inserting into a mySQL database, probably using Active Record.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
@token = Service.where(:provider => 'facebook', :user_id => session[:user_id]).first.token
@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@token) 
@feeds = params[:page] ? @graph.get_page(params[:page]) : @graph.get_connections("me", "home")
```

And here is what @feeds looks like:

```
    [{"id"=>"1519989351_1799856285747", "from"=>{"name"=>"April Daggett Swayne", "id"=>"1519989351"},
"picture"=>"http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/270060_1799856805760_1519989351_31482916_3866652_s.jpg",
"link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1799856805760&set=a.1493877356465.2064294.1519989351&type=1", "name"=>"Mobile Uploads",
"icon"=>"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yx/r/og8V99JVf8G.gif", "type"=>"photo", "object_id"=>"1799856805760", "application"=>{"name"=>"Facebook for Android",
"id"=>"350685531728"}, "created_time"=>"2011-07-03T03:14:04+0000", "updated_time"=>"2011-07-03T03:14:04+0000"}, {"id"=>"2733058_10100271380562998", "from"=>{"name"=>"Joshua Ramirez",
"id"=>"2733058"}, "message"=>"Just posted a photo",
"picture"=>"http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=124024574287414&v=1&size=z&cksum=228788edbab39cb34861aecd197ff458&src=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.instagram.com%2Fmedia%2F2011%2F07%2F02%2F2ad9768378cf405fad404b63bf5e2053_7.jpg",
"link"=>"http://instagr.am/p/G1tp8/", "name"=>"jtrainexpress's photo", "caption"=>"instagr.am",
"icon"=>"http://photos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/10/124024574287414/app_2_124024574287414_6936.gif", "actions"=>[{"name"=>"Comment",
"link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/2733058/posts/10100271380562998"}, {"name"=>"Like", "link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/2733058/posts/10100271380562998"}], "type"=>"link",
"application"=>{"name"=>"Instagram", "id"=>"124024574287414"}, "created_time"=>"2011-07-03T02:07:37+0000", "updated_time"=>"2011-07-03T02:07:37+0000"},
{"id"=>"588368718_10150230423643719", "from"=>{"name"=>"Eric Bailey", "id"=>"588368718"}, "link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Martis-Camp/105474549513998", "name"=>"Martis Camp",
"caption"=>"Eric checked in at Martis Camp.", "description"=>"Rockin the pool", "icon"=>"http://www.facebook.com/images/icons/place.png", "actions"=>[{"name"=>"Comment",
"link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/588368718/posts/10150230423643719"}, {"name"=>"Like", "link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/588368718/posts/10150230423643719"}],
"place"=>{"id"=>"105474549513998", "name"=>"Martis Camp", "location"=>{"city"=>"Truckee", "state"=>"CA", "country"=>"United States", "latitude"=>39.282813917575,
"longitude"=>-120.16736760768}}, "type"=>"checkin", "application"=>{"name"=>"Facebook for iPhone", "id"=>"6628568379"}, "created_time"=>"2011-07-03T01:58:32+0000",
"updated_time"=>"2011-07-03T01:58:32+0000", "likes"=>{"data"=>[{"name"=>"Mike Janes", "id"=>"725535294"}], "count"=>1}}]
```

I have looked around for clues on this, and haven't found it yet (but I'm still working on my stackoverflow-foo).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: might be a good idea to give a short example of what you have and what you want to see - it's not obvious to me from your question what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a Ruby Hash, that's a fragment of a JSON string. First you need to decode into a Ruby data structure:

```
# If your JSON string is in json...
h = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json) # Or your favorite JSON decoder.
```

Now you'll have a Hash in `h` so you can access it like any other Hash:

```
array = h['data']
puts array[0]['id']
# prints out 1111111111_0000000000000
puts array[0]['from']['name']
# prints Jane Done
```

Comment: I tried the path of using a JSON decoder, but it didn't like the stream I got back.  It always complained about it not being a string.  If what you say is true, and I just screwed up the JSON decode, then I should be able to have each post, witch starts with a "id", put into an array, and then access each part of the post on demand?  (Can you tell I come from objective C background - keep trying to think in terms of NSMutableArray ;)

Comment: @macboyrules: Your updated `@feeds` sample does look like decoded JSON so it looks like you could start with `@feeds[0]` and `@feeds[0]['id']` and things like that.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  So, my biggest problem was that I was trying to process something that was already processed :p